# How can I get a list of comments by target

Tags: comments, database, query

I've been looking at the classes [WP_Comment_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) and [WP_Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) but to be honest, I can't figure out how to use them together. I want to query the database for comments where `wp_posts::post_author == X` and `wp_comments::comment_post_id == wp_posts::post_id`. Could anybody give an example of usage?

Since SQL is not my thing, and this next question is not really WP related, but how would a SQL query be built to handle 2 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to retrieve posts, it's supposed to call [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

`WP_Query` has an argument called `meta_query` but it doesn't have `comment_query`.

So it might need a trick to achieve what you want,

```
$args = array();
$args['feed'] = 1;
$args['withcomments'] = 1;
$args['author'] = 1; //author id.
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$posts = $query->posts;
//do what you want
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Please note that, the $args may need more values such as post_status and posts_per_page. I'm just giving you a general idea here.

It'll generate two SQL queries:

```
SELECT wp_comments . * 
FROM wp_comments
JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID ) 
WHERE comment_approved =  '1'
AND (
wp_posts.post_author =1
)
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'post'
AND (
wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status =  'private'
)
GROUP BY wp_comments.comment_id
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC 



SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1 =1
AND wp_posts.ID
IN ( 528, 1 ) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

The second SQL query will retrieve posts by posts IDs which returned from 1st SQL.

---

I would recommend using custom SQL query for your task

```
SELECT wp_posts . * 
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_comments ON ( wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID ) 
WHERE comment_approved =  '1'
AND (
wp_posts.post_author =1
)
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'post'
AND wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
```

Comment: I think you're right about using the query.